# In-game sound gone after playing a while

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, technical-issues

After starting the game and playing for a while, suddenly the screen flicked, there's another white cursor, and **the sound is gone**, all of it.

There seems to be a lot of factors that caused this to happen: fast travel, fighting, strolling, etc. **So maybe I can say it is affected by the in-game time?** Please help, it's really annoying to keep restarting the game every time it occurs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So just the sound is gone?  Game is still responsive and everything?  What are you playing on (PC, 360, etc)?

Comment: Did this happen just once or does this happen regularly? Does restarting the game solve the issue?

Comment: Do you happen to have a dual-monitor setup and are just playing on one? I know there are issues around that, not sure I've heard it related to sound previously, but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

Does sound still play from other programs? Check if eg. Youtube works - if **not**, it's that your computer processor got "into delay" and somehow left the sound behind, or stopped the sound because it was too loud ( = are you using headphones?).

If other sound sources work well, it's a problem of Skyrim - a bug/glitch or something. You could try reinstalling the game if it really annoys you